# Adding a new locale to a Dojo widget

Tags: localization, internationalization, dojo

I use the DojoX Enhanced Grid widget, which comes with translations for a few languages(locales) built in:
See http://svn.dojotoolkit.org/src/tags/release-1.6.1rc2/dojox/grid/enhanced/nls/

If I want to add a new locale (let's say cn (chinese) or ru (russian)), how do I do that?

If I were hosting Dojo locally, that would be rather trivial (I would just add a folder under the dojox/grid/enhanced/nls/ directory for the locale of my choice and provide translations over there), but in my case, I have dojo loaded from a CDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the correct locale code for chinese is zh, not cn. Both chinese and russian are already supported by dojox/grid.

I don't think there's a way to add a new language, (say Hindi or Latin), without hosting dojo locally. Even with dojo hosted locally, it's not a trivial matter of adding a new folder for that locale; there's something more to be done with it that I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

That is quite easy. You can configure many global properties (including locale) via dojo config object, **before** dojo.js is loaded. http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/dojo_config/